# Refactor when renaming file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working with nodejs in Visual Studio Code and would like to refactor my code when renaming a file. I mean by that, that if I change the filename, also the filename with `require` should also change?

Is there such an option in VSC?

Appreciate your reply!

Comment: you mean in all the places where you have require('./filename') in the entire code base ?

Comment: @sreenivas Exactly. Is there such an option in VSC?

Comment: Not yet implemented. The closest you can do is rename the file and then search and replace 'require(<old_name>)' with 'require(<new_name>)'. If its just for a specific language it can be automated with an extension tough!

Comment: Found an extension which does that. Let me know if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: @sreenivas Please share the extension name with us. Thx in advance!

Comment: I modified the answer to add the extension. Here it is anyway...https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tnrich.js-path-refactor

Answer (score 1):

VSCode don't support this feature yet! Its under consideration and can be voted [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19439). Meanwhile you can use this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tnrich.js-path-refactor)